# ModelForm is not insert data correctly

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a database table for a comment and for a news story. The form for adding a comment is a ModelForm and i only include the comment_text field.

Models:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    story_text = models.TextField()
    comments = models.ForeignKey(Comments)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    emailOnReply = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment_text
```

Form:

```
class NewComment(ModelForm):
    """ Form for adding a new comment """
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment_text']
        widgets = {
            'comment_text': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

The view just checks if a POST request is received and then tries to validate the data before it saves the data. When i add print statements to the code i get in the log that the form is validated and the database table comment is updated, but when i extract database about a story it doesnt show any comments assosicated with the story.

I also tried to exchange the field with the foreign key of the Story table, so the comments attribute on the Story table is used in the NewForm class instead of comment_text, but then i dont get any value in the database table Story or Comment, it just says that it validates and it doesnt update the comments field...it does however create a whole new new story with all empty fields except for the fields date_added and data_modified.

Obviously im misunderstanding something here, can someone give me an idea of what im doing wrong? i *have* read the django docs about making queries, foreign key relation ships, related manager and so on, but clearly im misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Story having

```
comments = models.ForeignKey(Comments)
```

add this to the Comment class:

```
story = models.ForeignKey(Story, related_name='comments')
```

You will also need to set a value for this field when saving the comment.

Django then lets you access the comments for a story like this (for example in the code for a view):

```
story.comments.all()
```

Comment: After having tried this a couple of times i dont get what you mean, can you explain a little further. Do you want me to not have any comments attribute in the Story table and only have a story attribute in the Comment table that holds the comments ? When i have implemented that the form is never validating, im trying to insert data into the story foreign key attribute you specified above

Comment: just to add, i have added the form.comments.errors field but nothing is being printed out...ive used it on other forms and it works well but this time it doesnt output anything

Comment: just to specify, im not looking for counting the comments but saving and display all of them

Comment: found out about the validation error but what you are writing is to insert data straight into the foreign key which is an integer which have to equal a story..and not how to save the comment text which i was after..thanks anyway though but its the text i need saved